# request.GetBufferedInputStream is not seek enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stream, .net-4.5

Before .NET 4.5, I was using request.InputStream to read the data and save it to a database. However, now instead of using the "Classic" input stream reading mechanism, it uses the Buffered Input Stream.

In a module, when I try to read the stream, I have to check for the mode. But I can't read the BufferedInputStream because it's already read and it's not seekable.

Basically I have this in a module

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.EndRequest += EndRequest;
}

private void EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var request = application.Request;

    Stream requestInputStream = null;
    if (application.Request.ReadEntityBodyMode == ReadEntityBodyMode.Buffered)
    {
        // This is not readable...
        requestInputStream = request.GetBufferedInputStream();
    }
    else
    {
        requestInputStream = request.InputStream;
    }
}
```

My only trick I have found now, is to access the request.InputStream in a `BeginRequest` then save the stream at that point. However, my stream will stay in classic mode forever; I believe this is defeating the purpose of this .NET 4.5 buffered input stream.

Is there a better way to read this BufferedInputStream now?

(Full Code Open Source: [RequestLoggerModule.cs](https://github.com/jsgoupil/request-logger-module/blob/a3f989e329275f222f54b04d319dcbb36944e948/src/RequestLoggerModule/RequestLoggerModule.cs))

Comment: you probably don't want to do this in the RequestEnd event. Are you sure no one calls Request.Form or Request.Files etc during the processing of this request? Because in either case, all the content will already be read when EndRequest is fired. Reading the input stream by small buffers was already available in earlier versions of .net. It just depends on during which phase of execution you are accessing the stream.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks for the feedback. Now that .NET 4.5 will use the buffered stream, do you have an idea of how and when would you read the request stream?

Comment: Yes. You can read the stream with GetBufferedInputStream in PreRequestHandlerExecute event handler. This event handler is invoked just before ASP.NET starts executing an event handler (a page, a custom handler, a web service etc..) and we can expect the request to be not read fully at this point If no other http module have read it already. Using this particular event handler ensures that the request is authenticated, the session is available, and the actual handler is known (Which are probably needed for logging)